# How to search with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I need to make a search bar to find `h1` in divs but I need also to hide the hall div not only `h1` that not matches I found this on w3school but I don't know how `$(this)` works I need to select the div with class `blog-card`

```
        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." />


<div class="blog-card col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://storage.googleapis.com/chydlx/codepen/blog-cards/image-1.jpg)"></div>
                <ul class="details">
                    <li class="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
                    <li class="date">Aug. 24, 2015</li>
                    <li class="tags">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h1>Learning to Code</h1>
                <h2>Opening a door to the future</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad eum dolorum architecto obcaecati enim dicta praesentium, quam nobis! Neque ad aliquam facilis numquam. Veritatis, sit.</p>
                <p class="read-more">
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".blog-card .description h1").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal code that you've tried so far? So that we can understand the problem thoroughly...

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: i added html code

Comment: Where and what is the element with the id `myInput`? It's not in your code

Comment: before the div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." />
<div class="blog-card col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="meta">
            <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://storage.googleapis.com/chydlx/codepen/blog-cards/image-1.jpg)"></div>
            <ul class="details">
                <li class="author"><a href="#">John Doe</a></li>
                <li class="date">Aug. 24, 2015</li>
                <li class="tags">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h1>Learning to Code</h1>
            <h2>Opening a door to the future</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad eum dolorum architecto obcaecati enim dicta praesentium, quam nobis! Neque ad aliquam facilis numquam. Veritatis, sit.</p>
            <p class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read More</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").on("keyup", function () {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $(".blog-card .description h1").filter(function () {
                $(this).parent(".description").parent(".blog-card").toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchbuttonid').on('click',function(){
        $(".blog-card h1").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).attr('Id'));
        });
    });
});
```

This code will return all the `h1` tag's Id in console in div with class `blogcard`

this line hits the event handler on clicking of search button

```
$('#searchbuttonid').on('click',function(){
```

then the `h1` element inside `blog-card` is searched by jquery
so it is written as

```
$(".blog-card h1").each(function(){
```

the reason we apply `.each` to select all `h1` in the main class

after entering into the function, it then gets all the Id's of the `h1` element in the loop using `$(this).attr('Id')`

then its printed on console using

```
console.log($(this).attr('Id'));
```

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: i don't have id for each one i just need to select this and go above to it's class

Comment: specify exact usage of h1 tag, then i can help you